# Data generate by javascript not displaying on the table

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript that populate the arry data on a table but somehow the data generated by javascript is not displaying on the table. the table have two column and four rows.

I have created a javascript function to do that but the data it is not displaying on the html template. it must be something very simple, but i cannot seem to figure out what the problem is.

```js
const animalList = [
    "chicken", 3,
    "cow", 8,
    "dog", 2,
    "elephant", 4
];


function createAnimalList() {

    var table = document.getElementById("table-body");
    var tbody = table.createTBody(table);

    for (var i = 0; i < animalList.length; i++) {
        var row = tbody.insertRow(0);
        row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${animalList[i]}</td>
    `;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where, when and how are you calling this function?

Comment: iam calling the function from the html template onload even

Comment: Typo: `animalList` is not `animallist`

Comment: @bambam, there is no syntax error. And why `row.innerHTML +=`? Every row is different.

Comment: Right, already edited the comment @trincot. The formatting tricked me. The other point is also right, my bad. Should be `insertRow(i)` though

Comment: I fix the typo but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Please provide a runnable fiddle that demonstrates the problem

Comment: For instance, it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/ej3L2ayn/ But you must be sure to call the function when the document is ready, that you have a table element with the expected ID, and that it is not hidden.

Comment: it works perfectly when i tried , make sure the function is called or a table with `id = "table-body"` exist

Comment: not sure why its not working for me, my html  <body onload="createAnimalList()">

<div class="container">

    <h1 id="blue">My Animal List</h1>
    <table class="tab-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body">
      

        </tbody>
    </table>


</table>
</div>

Comment: I think it should be       var tbody = table.createTBody(); when you create body